# How do I create a header or footer button bar for my Android application

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, header, footer

Many popular apps like Google Maps, Facebook, Foursquare, etc. have header and/or footer bars on most of their activities. These headers often include very useful buttons, and
I would like to create one for my app. Does anyone know how they are done? I haven't been able to find anything so far.

Here are some pictures of what I mean:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/calebgomer/6262815430
http://www.flickr.com/photos/calebgomer/6262815458

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using this way you can make your `header-footer xml` and use it to any of your `activity` also you just need to **write code for the controls** in header-footer once in **HeaderFooter.java** and can access it your project.

**Build your HederFooter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="10"
    android:id="@+id/commonlayout" android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llheader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bar" android:layout_weight="1">



        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button_HeaderFooterSubscribe"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/subscribe"
                />
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button_logout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/logout"
                />
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button_playlist"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@drawable/tempadd"
                />



</RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lldata"
        android:layout_weight="8" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:background="#FFFFFF">


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llfooter"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible" android:background="@drawable/fbg"
        android:weightSum="5.0" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">

        <Button android:id="@+id/home" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/home" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="10px"></Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/issue" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/issue" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="10px"></Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/browse" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/browse" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="10px"></Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/search" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/search" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="10px"></Button>

        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/favorite"
            android:background="@drawable/favorite" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:padding="10px"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Then Create One HeaderFooter.java Activity**

```
public class HeaderFooter extends Activity {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.headerfooter);
        }
 }
```

**Now Extend above activity to your all other activities and inflate your particular view in the middle layout of the headerfooter.xml**

```
public class Home extends HeaderFooter 
{
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lldata);
            ViewGroup.inflate(Home.this, R.layout.home, vg);
        }
}
```

Comment: This approach worked very well, thanks!
(The only problem is that the footer has a very small gap between it and the bottom of the screen)

Comment: @CalebGomer i have updated xml use it and that problem will be solved..tell me if noy

Comment: @MKJParekh could you please add a sample code on how to listen to button clicks in the header ?? and I have a problem I can't extend the activity and inflate the header nothing is shown and I get no errors, any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: In the HeaderFooter activity only , you can write the button click event and that will be extended automatically to other classes..
In above code we are inflating data part in header footer xml..
@Moe

Comment: This is good technique. But I have one confusion about above approach. I do not need to add HeaderFooter in my manifest file. Anyone knows why?

Comment: @Chintan I couldn't get you.. share confusion here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat

Answer (score 2):

Just create a xml as you need.

Add these XML to your other screens using  tag in your other Screen XMLs.

[Sample is here.](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)

You can handle the button click as you need in each activity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have worked on android before. I have working apps, I just would like their GUI to look better. I will look at those samples and see what I can do.
Thanks!

Comment: @Vinay  Dont just give the link this link is broken. Please update your link.

Answer (score 0):

Design Xml layout with header,footer and body.you have to extend the main activity  every time,you have to change body by inflating desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think the element that you're liking in those layouts is the fact that they're using a FrameLayout for the lower part of the display.

They're probably doing something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical
  .../>
 <head layout element>
 <FrameLayout element>
 <footer layout element>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a difference between using a LinearLayout footer and using a FrameLayout for the footer?

Comment: It's not the footer that's the framelayout. It's the content pane that's the frame layout. I've edit my answer to be more specific.

Comment: I see what you mean. I changed the "body" from a LinearLayout to a FrameLayout but I didn't see a difference between the two. Are there practical advantages for using the FrameLayout in this situation?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I think they just look nicer.