# How to add header to Activity in Android

Tags: android, header

How to add a header to an existing android activity? All the examples that I found with a search engine are showing how to add a header to the list view.

Comment: Your question is not really specific enough.  I assume the Activity will be a View or View subclass.  The method of adding a "header" depends on which View you are using.

Comment: Need more description what do you mean by "add a header to an existing android activity?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a view the xml that you're using for your layout. So for example, say your Activity is using a linear layout. You'd do:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" ....>
  <LinearLayout....>
     <!---- Header Stuff Goes Here ---->
  </LinearLayout>
  <!--- Rest of the layout for your activity goes here ---->
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are looking for..might be **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831044/how-do-i-create-a-header-or-footer-button-bar-for-my-android-application/7831387#7831387)** is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a ActionBar, it is included on 3.0 api but if you want to use with backward compatibility you can use different libraries, my preferit is [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) you can also see an example downloading the [GreenDroid Catalog App](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cyrilmottier.android.gdcatalog&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5jeXJpbG1vdHRpZXIuYW5kcm9pZC5nZGNhdGFsb2ciXQ..) from Market.

I hope this helped you :)