# Top Button Menu bar for All Activities like Tab menu

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to include a top menu button bar and implement click functionality in  all activitys . Its like header file in websites. any idea how can i do that?

Comment: check this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831044/how-do-i-create-a-header-or-footer-button-bar-for-my-android-application/7831387#7831387)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)? It was introduced in Android 3.0, but with [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) support package you can use it on 2.x OS version

[image]

Comment: Yes I am looking for something like this. But i think action bar will be availabel from API version 11 and my minSdkVersion is 7. Can i use this support package to make my app compatible with action bar.

Comment: Sure - If you will use the support package you can use many featrues from new Android version on older releases. For the Action bar there is extension for the above mentioned support package called "Sherlock Action Bar" - http://actionbarsherlock.com/. We are using it and it works perfectly - check the samples available on the web page. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using API Version less than 3.0 use compatibility library, and use MenuCompact showAsAction

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuCompat.html#setShowAsAction(android.view.MenuItem, int)