# Static Title Bar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to my title bar be static.Means i dont want to move with other stuff .How can i do that?

MyCode:`

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="44dip"
                      android:layout_width="320dip"

                      android:background="@drawable/header_320_44dip">
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="121dip"
                    android:layout_height="32dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
                    android:background="@drawable/logo_121_32dip">

            </ImageView>
            <Button
                    android:layout_height="34dip"
                    android:layout_width="64dip"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_hello_what"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="38dip"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_nedit_nontext_64x34">
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: What do you mean you don't want it to move?  Where is it going?

Comment: custum title must be stack.Dont move.

Comment: you need to improve your question..

Answer (score 0):

```
 final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);


       if ( customTitleSupported ) 
         {

     getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
        }

        final TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
        if ( myTitleText != null ) 
          {
            myTitleText.setText("YOUR TITLE HERE");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set some header view to all your activity then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831044/how-do-i-create-a-header-or-footer-button-bar-for-my-android-application/7831387#7831387) may be helpful to you.

And you can also use the default title bar of the android app to customize [see this post](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/)