# Android: Manage UI height due to ads

Tags: user-interface, android-layout, height, footer

In my Android app I have set up a common footer for all activity.

Implemented like this [How do I create a header or footer button bar for my Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831044/how-do-i-create-a-header-or-footer-button-bar-for-my-android-application)  with a top most Activity "MyActivity".

In my other activity I code as:

```
public class TestActivity extends MyActivity implements OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "TEST";
private AlertDialog.Builder builder = null;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Pick up the group from head_foot.xml for middle data to be displayed
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lldata);
    ViewGroup.inflate(Mumbai77Activity.this, R.layout.main, vg);
```

In other activity, child of MyActivity where I create an AlertDialog thru Inflate Layout and display, the height of AlertDialog should be less than the height reached footer. How do I handle the height of the AlertDialog.

The code I use for creating dialog is :

```
    public AlertDialog createAlertDialog(String title, String[] items, OnItemClickListener clickListener) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater   = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              // scrollview1 is the root of this activiy layout
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gen_list_layout, vg, false);


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

I tried setting LayoutParams in AlertDialog for the Viewgroup, but it also didn't work.

How to make the AlertDialog's height same as scrollview's or lldata's height?

Comment: No helplines or guidance for this question !!!!

Comment: Any body  there to help me with this problem.